# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los verbos "quedar" y "quedarse"?

Tags: verbos

quisiera que me explicaseis las diferencias entre los verbos "quedar" y "quedarse" específicamente cuando se usan en frases como:

> El coche quedó inmovilizado.
>
> El niño se ha quedado dormido.

Ciertas fuentes explican que la versión no reflexiva suele usarse para hablar del resultado de una acción o situación mientras que la versión reflexiva se usa más bien para hablar de un cambio de situación, pero me cuesta entender precisamente por qué a mi amigo hispanohablante le suena rara la frase:

> El coche se quedó inmovilizado.

Gracias por adelantado por vuestra ayuda, llevo unos días intentando entender esto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El verbo "quedarse" es pronominal (no reflexivo) y, cuando va seguido de adjetivo, se utiliza para referirse a seres (personas, animales), **no a objetos**.

Puede emplearse para designar acciones voluntarias:

- El niño **se quedó** quieto.

o involuntarias:

- El niño **se quedó** dormido.

Cuando va seguido de adjetivo, el verbo intransitivo "quedar" puede utilizarse para referirse a objetos o personas (sólo para indicar un estado involuntario):

- La máquina quedó inutilizable.
- Quedó herido / Quedamos conformes (ejemplos tomados del [DRAE](https://dle.rae.es/quedar)).

No obstante, "quedarse" puede usarse con objetos cuando no hay adjetivo:

- El coche **se quedó** (dejó de andar).

El verbo "quedar" también puede usarse con otros significados, ajenos al sentido de verbo de proceso (similar a "ponerse" o "convertirse"), como puede observarse en la entrada del DRAE citada.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu explicación, me parece aclararlo todo. Ahora me toca practicar usar esta estructura hasta que me acostumbre.